# What's the best strategy to send btc from one wallet to a address list with transaction id for each payment?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, sendtoaddress, payment-batching

I'm triyng send a mass btc payment, but using "sendToAddress" i'm limited send a new transaction only when the last was confirmed, if i try send when the last was pending of confirmation i'll not have balance on my wallet because the my founds was send to change addresses and is pending.

If i use sendMany i'll only had transaction to all payments and i need an transaction to each address and get controll for the fees for each.

If i wait for the last confirm to send a new my batch payment will spend a lot of time and  will stuck my payment list, i'll limitaded for some payments for day.

What's is the best approuch to this problem? Can someone help me? I tried found solution in older topics but i don't had success with this, maybe i cant express myself correctely or do not know the correct terms.

Comment: You can spend unconfirmed BTC. Which wallet are you using?

Comment: i can use any wallet, what you recommend?

Comment: Try electrum or Bitcoin Core wallet

Comment: i'm programming an API to interact with btc core.

Comment: I was talking about these options: [bitcoin core](https://i.ibb.co/4psm1xr/image.png) [electrum](https://i.ibb.co/vxn9hWH/image.png)

Comment: @Prayank i'll search about, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `sendmany`.

It accepts a `minconf` parameter (which defaults to 1, for 1 confirmation) - it will spend outputs that have at least `minconf` number of confirmations.

Setting `minconf=0` will allow you to spend unconfirmed coins, such as from the change output of a previous `sendmany` transaction.

Comment: Cool, i'll make some tests with sendmany, i was trying send using sendtoaddress. Thanks!